# how to access the implementation Queryable.Count Method?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0, iqueryable

how to access the implementation [`Count<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.count?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Queryable_Count__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__) method?

That's the assembler code:
[image]

Comment: Hi @lotfi91. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) so to post better formatted and by the SO standard questions

Answer (score 0):

In the link you have given (description of Queryable.Count Method) it directly says that it depends on the type of the source parameter.

Meaning it "redirects" to the count implementation of the Type you have given of 'source' parameter

Remarks part:

**Count(IQueryable) depends on the implementation of the type of the source parameter. The expected behavior is that it counts the number of items in source.**

Comment: if for example;
         public static int <String> Count (this source IQueryable <String>),                          how to access the implementation ?  Thanks   @Bratumił Rynkiewicz